# Console crashes in C during a for loop

Tags: c, crash, sdl, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

So I'm beginning a game in SDL and C, and during the first hours, with only 2 functions and not so many lines, I get a crash of the console. I got a 2D array of a type structure wich contains the structure `SDL_Rect` (for the coordinates of surfaces with the `int x,y`).

I made a function to initialize all my coordinates of my array by using two `for` loop. The error seems to be occurring at the end of the 2nd iteration of the 1st loop, when the code go for a 3rd one. I made my guess in testing values of my array at each stage of the loops, before and after each assignement.

Here's my function:

```
void InitializeCoordinate(BrickStruct (*Grid)[10][12])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<12;j++)
        {
            Grid[i][j]->Coordinate.x = j*80;
            Grid[i][j]->Coordinate.y = i*40;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my structure:

```
typedef struct BrickStruct
{
    int type;
    SDL_Rect Coordinate;   //Struct using 2 int x,y to define coordinates of a surface
}BrickStruct;
```

And in my main, I create the `Grid` structure and I pass my `Grid` to my function. This is between `SDL_Surface *ecran=NULL;` and `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)`  :

```
BrickStruct Grid[10][12];
InitializeCoordinate(&Grid);
```

That's everything. I'm stuck for several hours with my colleague on this. The console code errors reports we get were -1073741510 and -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
Maybe a good soul will want to guide us towards the good path ? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `void InitializeCoordinate(BrickStruct Grid[10][12])` and `Grid[i][j].Coordinate.x = j*80;` and `InitializeCoordinate(Grid);`. Array parameters are always passed by pointer and not by value so don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to a 2d array.

What you do is:

```
 Grid[i][j]->Coordinate.x = ...
```

which is equal to this:

```
 *(Grid[i][j]).Coordinate.x = ...
```

but that is wrong, you don't want to do arithmetic on the pointer, but your array. So you have to dereference the pointer first to access the array:

```
 (*Grid)[i][j].Coordinate.x = ...
```

this way you access the array and *then* do the operations on it.

Comment: This is correct, but as a side note, the pointer is totally unnecessary for this function. Just pass the array directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because I don't like the `*()` or `(*)` ways of using pointers and I always prefer use the `->` instead (for the convenience, habits and ease of reading): is there any other way of doing that other than `(*Grid)[i][j].Coordinate.x = ...` ?


And I wonder why the pointer is unnecessary here ? Because at the end I want to change the value of my array so I need the addresses of my array to be passed into my function ?! or not ?

Comment: @paolovador You can't change the array, and the array decays to a pointer so you don't have to pass the address of it.

Comment: @paolovador: I don't think you want to change the value of your array variable. You want to change the elements in your array. You can do that just by passing the array, since passing an array just passes a pointer to its start rather than copying its value as passing a struct would do.